# Android countdown timer display milliseconds?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I want a timer to pop up when I click a button that will count down from 3 seconds. And it does that fine but i want it to also show the milliseconds so when I click the button the text would go from 3.0 to 0.1. How would I add the milliseconds to the text view?

```
new CountDownTimer(1000, 3000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    textViewTimer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    textViewTimer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    textViewLevelGained.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
            }.start();
```

This is what I have

Comment: but u have already added millisUntilFinished to textViewTimer in onTick . u have any issue with it?

Comment: it just counts down from 3...2....1... and doesn't display the milliseconds. I want it to count from 3.0, 2.9, 2.8, etc...

Answer (score 7):

Other SO questions suggest CountDownTimer doesn't do sub 1-second granularity well. Look into a different class, like TimerTask.

Otherwise, the following would work.

```
new CountDownTimer(3000, 1) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        textViewTimer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000
          + "." + millisUntilFinished % 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        textViewTimer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        textViewLevelGained.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: That's not working. It just displays "2.189, 1.189" then stops

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change the increment amount.

Comment: the first value of CountDownTimer needs to be 3000
but its still just showing 2.2, 1.1, then stops. theres no 2.9, 2.8, 2.7, see what i'm saying?

Comment: Even with `CountDownTimer(3000, 1)`?

Comment: Other SO questions suggest CountDownTimer doesn't do sub 1-second granularity well. Look into a different class, like TimerTask.